# Между тем - вводное слово?

Tags: синтаксис

Когда "между тем" является вводным словом? Видела его в списках ложных вводных слов, но в литературе иногда встречала варианты с запятой...
Предложение из варианта ЕГЭ:
Два друга между тем были так увлечены беседой, что, кажется, и не заметили, как наступил рассвет.

Answer (score 6):

МЕЖДУ ТЕМ, наречие, союз и член предложения

- Наречие. То же, что «в то же время, тем временем». Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

Алексей  между тем пристально глядел на молодую крестьянку.  Дети между тем бегали по улице оборванные, неумытые; весьма вероятно, часто даже бывали голодны.

- Союз. Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «между тем» выделяются знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.

Стрелять могли только немцы и только в них, между тем отсюда не видно было шоссе, значит, не видно и немцев.

- Член предложения. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

Можно сесть и прямо, но тогда надо ноги, положив их одну на другую, просунуть между тем самым ящиком, где лежало письмо, и доской, которая прикрывает батарею парового отопления.

По приведенному Вами примеру видно, что МЕЖДУ ТЕМ можно заменить «в то же время, тем временем». Значит, это наречие, которое не выделяется запятыми.

Answer (score 2):

Это действительно не вводное слово, потому что или выполняет роль  союза (Но два друга были так увлечены беседой...),или  претендует на роль обстоятельства, как, например,в вашем случае: Два друга между тем (в это время) были так увлечены беседой, что, кажется, и не заметили, как наступил рассвет. В Вашем случае это точно не вводное.

В художественных текстах встречается обособление, когда придаётся уступительное значение "несмотря на это", тогда это не вводное, а обособленное обстоятельство. Бывают случаи, когда "между тем " вносит значение сомнения, недоверия, тогда раньше их относили к вводным, сейчас во всех справочниках написано, что не является вводным.

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях к тотальному экзамену есть такое пояснение:

Он между тем продолжал.
Не рекомендуется: Он, между тем, продолжал.
между тем – запятые не ставятся, так как это наречное выражение, выполняющее в предложении функцию обстоятельства времени (=тем временем, в то же время). В словаре В. М. Пахомова, В. В. Свинцова, И. В. Филатовой это сочетание определяется как наречие или как союз.
Ни в том, ни в другом случае постановка запятых не требуется [Пахомов, Свинцов, Филатов 2012: 247–248]. 
В словаре О. А. Остроумовой и О. Д. Фрамполь отмечается возможность употребления в роли вводного сочетания: «Неустойчиво вводное, решение об обособлении принимает автор: между тем обособляется в функции вводного для выделения какого-либо факта, при желании придать ему оттенок попутного замечания (=к слову сказать), интонационно выделяется. 
Ср.: В комнате, между тем (=к слову сказать), потемнело (В. Набоков). – В комнате между тем (= тем временем) потемнело. 
В функции вводного слова обособляется: А день, между тем, был не обычный – самый последний в году, а может быть, и в столетии (Б. Акунин);
 В столовой, между тем, братцу и мне велено было продолжать есть (В. Набоков); 
Между тем, Роза Шполянская, заметив, что Пнин сидит в одиночестве, и воспользовавшись этим, подошла к нему («сидите, сидите!») и опустилась рядышком на скамью (В. Набоков). 
В функции обстоятельства не обособляется: Оратор между тем отпил из стакана и продолжал (А. Куприн)» [Остроумова, Фрамполь 2009: 203–204]. В данном тексте это сочетание выполняет обстоятельственную функцию, поэтому не выделяется. 
Предположительно возможна (хотя и маловероятна) интерпретация, в которой данное сочетание окажется вводным (ср.: Он, однако, продолжал), поэтому мы допускаем здесь постановку парных запятых.

Answer (score 0):

Список ложных вводных слов - это, конечно, интересно. Некоторые пользователи, действительно, идут по ложному пути и обособляют "между тем" безо всяких на то оснований.

И все же **вводное слово "между тем" существует**, просто его значение связано не со временем (=тем временем), а с противопоставлением, сопоставлением, уступкой, то есть когда **сравниваются  ситуации**, например:

(1) Между тем, эффективность стандартизации **находит** подтверждение на международном уровне в  развитых и развивающихся странах.

(2) Между тем, выигрыш в преферансе **зависит не только от полученных игроком карт**, не только от его умения играть, но и от способности в нужный момент переломить игру…

При обособлении **исключается значение времени**, которое имело бы необособленное наречие.

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксический статус сочетания "между тем" определяется не словарями, а передаваемой информацией, т.е. речевой ситуацией. А словари лишь своевременно или с опозданием фиксируют то, что находит отражение в речи. Мой ответ: это словосочетание полифункционально. В речи оно может выполнять разные функции, в том числе и функцию вводного компонента. И НЕ СЛОВАРЬ ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТ ЕГО СТАТУС, А ПЕРЕДАВАЕМОЕ СОДЕРЖАНИЕ. Иными словами, его статус определяется волей автора.